# Having trouble sorting array list alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I've been having trouble being able to `sort my outputs into alphabetical order` (by the name). I've tried a few `methods`, they've been commented out. The latest method I tried is the `bubble sort`.

My program is writing all the inputs to a binary file and then reading them when the user wants to output them. So basically when the user clicks the number 5, it will `run` the `sortEmployees()` method and then display the records in alphabetical order, but at the moment I haven't found a way to do that.

I'm not confident with array lists, I haven't used them that much...So I'm almost certain im using the wrong `methods`. Im not using the latest JDK I believe. I've also looked at different questions on stack + google and can't really find much that helps.

Output at the moment is as follows:

1. 1, Johnson, 80000.00
2. 2 So on...
3. 3 and so on... As they've been entered below.

I'll add all my code below, so you can have a look at it.

### EmployeeFileDriver.java

```
    java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class EmployeeFileDriver
    {   
        private static ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
            final int QUIT_MAIN_MENU = 4;
            String fileName = "Employee.txt";

            readEmployeeFile(fileName);
            //sample records
            list.add(new Employee(1, "Johnson", 80000.00));
            list.add(new Employee(2, "Singh",  75000.00));
            list.add(new Employee(3, "Smith", 63000.00));
            list.add(new Employee(4, "Jones", 52000.00));

            int choice = mainMenu();

            while(choice != QUIT_MAIN_MENU)  
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        list.add(inputEmployee());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        searchID();
                        break; 
                    case 3:
                        listAllEmployees();
                        break;   
                    case 5:
                        sortEmployees(list[]);
                        break;
                } //end switch (choice)  

                choice = mainMenu();  // recall mainMenu()
            } // end while

            saveEmployeeFile(fileName);  //save objects to file before closing
            System.out.println("Records saved to file");
        }

        public static int mainMenu()
        {
            String heading, menu, userSelection;

            heading = "<h3><u>EMPLOYEE SYSTEM</u></h3>";

            menu =  "<HTML><center>" + heading + "<hr><h2><u>Main Menu</u></h2><br /><table>" + 
                    "<tr><td>1.  Enter Employee Details</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>2.  Search Employee ID</td></tr>" + 
                    "<tr><td>3.  List all Employees</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>4.  Save and Exit</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>5.  Sort alphabetically</td></tr>" +
                    "</table><br /><hr></center></HTML>" +
                    "\nEnter Selection: ";

            //get user selection for main menu
            userSelection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , menu,"Input",  
                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            int option = Integer.parseInt(userSelection);

            //return option to main method
            return option;
        }

        public static void readEmployeeFile(String fileName)
        {
            try 
            {
               //open InputFile
                FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(fiStream);

                list = (ArrayList)inStream.readObject();  //read whole ArrayList object 
                                                          //rather than individual Employee objects

                System.out.println("\tEMPLOYEE LIST (from File)");
                System.out.println("ID    \t   Name   \t    Salary\n");
                for(Employee e: list)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%-10d %-16s $%8.2f\n", e.getID(), 
                                            e.getName(), e.getSalary());
                }           
                inStream.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Could not open file\n" + e.toString());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Class not found \n" + e.toString());
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Employee file: \n" + e.toString());
            }   
        }

        //save employee objects to file on exit
        public static void saveEmployeeFile(String fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                //open OutputFile
                FileOutputStream foStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
                ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(foStream);

                outStream.writeObject(list);  //save whole ArrayList object to file

                outStream.close();                      
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Could not open file\n" + e.toString());
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("I/O error\n" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        public static Employee inputEmployee()
        {
            int id;
            String name;
            double salary;
            Employee emp;

            id = Integer.parseInt(
                   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Enter employee ID"));
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Enter employee name");
            salary = Double.parseDouble(
                   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null , "Enter employee salary"));
            emp = new Employee(id, name, salary);

            return emp;
        }

        public static void searchID()
        {
            int id;
            boolean found = false;

            id = Integer.parseInt(
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter employee ID to search"));

            for(Employee e: list)
            {
                if(id == e.getID())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(found == false)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee ID not found"); 
        }

        public static void listAllEmployees()
        {
            String output = "";

            for(Employee e: list)
            {
                output += e.toString();
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
        }

    //    public void sortEmployees(){
    //        //Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e1.getname().compareTo(e2.id()));
    //        //[list sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    //            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Employee>()
    //            {
    //                @Override
    //                public int compare(String name)
    //                {
    //                    return name.compareToIgnoreCase("ABCDE");
    //                }
    //            });
    //    }
        public static void sortEmployees()
        {

            int j;
                boolean flag = true;  // will determine when the sort is finished
                String temp;

                while ( flag )
                {
                      flag = false;
                      for ( j = 0;  j < list.length - 1;  j++ )
                      {
                              if ( list [ j ].compareToIgnoreCase( list [ j+1 ] ) > 0 )
                              {                                             // ascending sort
                                          temp = list [ j ];
                                          list [ j ] = list [ j+1];     // swapping
                                          list [ j+1] = temp; 
                                          flag = true;
                               } 
                       } 
          } 
            String output = "";
            for(String e: list)
            {
                output += e.toString();
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
        }    
    }
```

### Employee.java

```
    public class Employee 
    {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private double salary;


        public Employee (int id, String name,  double salary) 
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;   
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public double getSalary()
        {
            return this.salary;
        }

        public int getID()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "\nID_NO:\t"+id+"\nNAME:\t"+name+"\nSALARY\t"+salary+"\n"; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried: Collections.sort()? already?

Comment: You shouldn't be implementing a sorting algorithm yourself; just implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for your object and use `Collections.sort`

Comment: Why are you implementing your own sort method, and a bad one at that? You should be using more efficient sort methods. I think you'll find that Java has already facilities for sorting lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
static List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

static void sortEmployees() {
    list.sort(new Comparator<Employee>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
            return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
        }});
}
```

Note `list.sort(...)` is available since Java 8. For Java 7 and before use  `Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Employee>() {...});`

---

With java8 streams, if you want to keep the original order:

```
List<Employee> sortedList = list.stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Another variant is to have `Employee` implements the `Comparable` interface and use the *natural* ordering on `Employee` objects (as you define it - which is alphabetic order on names):

```
public class Employee implements Comparable {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Employee e = (Employee)o;
        return name.compareTo(e.getName());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can just do (Java 8):

```
static void sortEmployees() {
    list.sort(null); // passing a null Comparator => use natural order
}
```

Or in Java 7 and before:

```
static void sortEmployees() {
    Collections.sort(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the all object by name then you need to use **Comparator** or **Camparable** interface.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

}
```

Also you need to override **compareto** method.

```
@Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
```

Check following links for more details.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/01/java-comparator-example-for-custom.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Hope it may help you.!!

Comment: Hey @Ranjitsinh I'm sure this works as well but AbbeResina's method worked really really well! I haven't tried your one.